# How to iterate array of objects in jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

```
I am trying to iterate API response in jQuery ajax call but I'm getting undefined data for all elements. how to iterate an array of objects in jQuery. I'm new to iteration in api ajax call
```

I want to iterate each object name , imageLink and date based on API response length
for example: Name: aadhar , attachment:img link, date: today date like this format all div box's should repeated based on an array object length.
anyone can please help me on it. I have spend more time already on it but I'm unable to achieve it.

```
request: if possible please show me in Jsfiddle and let me know where I did wrong



<script>
// this is my api response.
{
  "status": true,
  "timestamp": "2023-04-25T13:16:41:799",
  "message": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "30_AADHAR_1.jpg",
      "imageLink": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/kbe-test-crops/Sula/KBE/kyc/identity/30_AADHAR_1.jpg",
      "date": "2023-04-24T09:52:51.000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "30_AADHAR_2.jpg",
      "imageLink": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/kbe-test-crops/Sula/KBE/kyc/identity/30_AADHAR_2.jpg",
      "date": "2023-04-24T10:18:01.000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "30_AADHAR_3.jpg",
      "imageLink": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/kbe-test-crops/Sula/KBE/kyc/identity/30_AADHAR_3.jpg",
      "date": "2023-04-24T10:34:16.000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "30_AADHAR_4.jpg",
      "imageLink": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/kbe-test-crops/Sula/KBE/kyc/identity/30_AADHAR_4.jpg",
      "date": "2023-04-24T11:05:07.000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "30_AADHAR_5.jpg",
      "imageLink": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/kbe-test-crops/Sula/KBE/kyc/identity/30_AADHAR_5.jpg",
      "date": "2023-04-24T13:00:12.000+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
</script>

    function ApplicationForm(){
            
                var person = document.getElementById("personIdenty").value;
                var appfile = document.getElementById("applicationfm").value;
                var baseUrl = document.getElementById("bridge").value;
                var formData = new FormData();
                   
                   formData.append("documentCategory",appfile);
                   formData.append("personId",person);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseUrl+"/storeFiles/farmerkycImages",
                        
                         "processData": false,
                         "contentType": false,
                         method: 'POST',
                         dataType: 'json',
                         data: formData, 
                          
                         success: function(response) {
                            // var imgName = response.data.map(imgName => { return imgName.name });
                             //console.log(response);
                             $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                                 var kycdocs = `<div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2"><span><strong>File Name :</strong> </span></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><span id="imgname">${response.data.name}</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2"><span><strong>Image Url :</strong> </span></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><a href="" id="img-link" target="_blank">${response.data.imageLink}</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2"><span><strong>Date : </strong> </span></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><span id="img-date">${response.data.date}</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>`;
                                 $('#myDiv').append(kycdocs);

                             });
                              },
                        
                      }); 

                   }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"
            integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it seems what you are getting from api response is json, try
`JSON.parse( JSON.stringfy(yourAPIresponse) ) ` this will turn response to json string then to object.

Comment: Written as you suggested but getting error in console like this (4002:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
 )

Comment: Hi AkiZukiLenn,  I have added JSON.parse but it's getting Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON ) please suggest me better way.

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn  whatever I have getting that response  in browser , I have mentioned above please keep an eye on that

Comment: Make sure the API response is the one you mentioned in the code. If it is just {"status": true,....}. this should be a JSON object, a JSON.parse should make it works. But the error you received seems to suggest the other wise, that your api response is already an object you wish to be. Try to console log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to consider changing your .each call with something like this

```
if(response.data != undefined){
    $.each(response.data, function(obj, indx) {
         var kycdocs = `<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><span><strong>File Name :</strong> </span></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"><span id="imgname">${obj.name}</span></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><span><strong>Image Url :</strong> </span></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"><a href="" id="img-link" target="_blank">${obj.imageLink}</a></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><span><strong>Date : </strong> </span></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"><span id="img-date">${obj.date}</span></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>`;
         $('#myDiv').append(kycdocs);
    
     });
}
```